# display two different Video-Streams at the same time

Tags: iphone, stream, video-streaming, mpmovieplayer

**I try to display two different http/rtsp-Video-Streams at the same time on the same UIView.**

So my first thought was to use the UIViews of two MPMoviePlayerController.

But the documentation says:

*Note: Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie.*
Okey!

My second thought was to use the UIWebView.

But that also doesn't work. I can display only one stream.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, as the documentation says, only one Video can be shown at any point. Video has to be full Screen! check also: 
[Customizable non-full screen video player in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048074/customizable-non-full-screen-video-player-in-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's an interesting article but that's not what i am looking for. I guess FFmpeg is able to help me with the task.